# angular-cli - unit tests fail to run in VSTS?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli

I have created a project with angular-cli.
The unit test run fine in my local system.
When i run the tests as part of build, in VSTS i get the following error:

```
 > ng test --cc Your global Angular CLI version (1.4.9) is greater than your local version (1.4.7). The local Angular CLI version is used. To
> disable this warning use "ng set --global
> warnings.versionMismatch=false". [32m26 10 2017 04:28:02.079:INFO
> [karma]: [39mKarma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
> [32m26 10 2017 04:28:02.081:INFO [launcher]: **[39mLaunching browser
> ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with unlimited concurrency [32m26 10 2017
> 04:28:02.089:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser ChromeHeadless   
> [33m26 10 2017 04:29:02.092:WARN [launcher]: [**39mChromeHeadless have
> not captured in 60000 ms, killing****. [33m26 10 2017 04:29:04.095:WARN
> [launcher]: [**39mChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending
> SIGKILL**. [33m26 10 2017 04:29:06.095:WARN [launcher]:
> [**39mChromeHeadless was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing**.
>  Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The karma config looks like this:

```
> module.exports = function (config) {  config.set({        basePath: '',
>       frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],        plugins: [
>           require('karma-jasmine'),           require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
>           require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
>           require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
>           require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')       ],      client: {
>           clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in
> browser       },      coverageIstanbulReporter: {             reports: ['html',
> 'lcovonly'],          fixWebpackSourcePaths: true         },      mime: {
> 'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'] },         angularCli: {           environment:
> 'dev'         },      reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],      port: 9876,
>       colors: true,       logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,      autoWatch: false,
>       browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],      customLaunchers: {
>           ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
>               base: 'ChromeHeadless',
>               flags: [
>                   '--no-sandbox', // required to run without privileges
>                   '--disable-gpu',
>                   // Without a remote debugging port, Google Chrome exits immediately.
>                   '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
>               ]           }       },      captureTimeout: 60000,      singleRun: true,        browserNoActivityTimeout : 10000000     }); };
```

And package.json is below:

> ```
>   "private": true,
>   "dependencies": {
>     "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
>     "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
>     "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
>     "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
>     "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
>     "@angular/http": "^4.2.4"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "@angular/cli": "1.4.7",
>     "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
>     "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
>     "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
>     "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
>     "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
>     "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
>     "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
>     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
>     "karma": "~1.7.0",
>     "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
>     "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
>     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
>     "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0"
>   }
> }
> ```

Any help in solving the error is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don not need to install Angular CLI  on your VSTS agent globally, you can simply run:

`npm run ng -- t` - that will use the local project version of Angular CLI whatever version it is.

Second of all [VSTS does not support Headless chrome yet](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19387174-install-headless-chrome-on-hosted-build-servers)

So, try to set `browsers: ['Chrome']` instead to use the normal chrome browser.

Also you might want to try [VSTS Chromium Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=schlumberger.chromium-build-tasks-Preview) (currently in Preview, so might not work)

> FYI currently on our project we are rinning tests on VSTS with normal
>   Chrome and have no problems with that. In order to do that you have to install Chrome browser on your build agent machine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents.

Comment: why VSTS Chromium Build task might not work? we added this 'VSTS Chromium Build Tasks' to VSTS.

Comment: @user2439903 it is great if you get it workong. This task is a Preview version atm.

Comment: @user2439903 Just install a Chrome browser on your build agent machine and forget about Headless Chrome for now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents

Comment: Any idea on how to view the unit test results in xml format using angular-cli?